# Visual Studio - Increase Font Size for Statement Completion Description

Tags: visual-studio

I'm new to Visual Studio, and I'm trying to increase the size of the `Statement Completion 'Description'` editor UI window (highlighted in image) as I'm struggling to read it.

I've tried editing the following with no luck:

- Tools – Options – Environment - Fonts and Colors > Statement Completion
- Tools – Options – Environment - Fonts and Colors > Editor Tooltip

Neither of the above increases the size of the highlighted window. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: works for me. What version of Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: Not entirely sure why, but it has updated now. I restarted VS a few times before posting this so not sure what was causing the issue.

Comment: Was using VS Community '22, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

After restarting Visual Studio a few times (3?) this seemed to update and show the `Statement Completion` description window in an increased font size.